# if-condition in Order update EmailTemplate

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-status

I like to use differrent text for order_update email template.

Admin->Marketing->Email template i create new template for "order update"

If `$order.getStatusLabel() == "Cancel"` I like to add some custom text. How to add `$order.getStatusLabel() == "Cancel"` in if condition or `{{depend}}`.

I used if condition in
[image]

but my result getting:

[image]

Please let me know

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use block like below

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' 
area='frontend' template='Vendor_Module::email/order_update/statusinfo.phtml' order=$order}}
```

Then Create a custom template file and add below condition

```
<?php if($this->getData('order')->getStatusLabel() == 'Canceled') {
        echo "<p>Order status is cancel</p>"; 
      } else {
            echo "<p>Order status is not cancel</p>";
       }

?>
```

Comment: we can't directly use in Admin->Marketing->Email template-> "edit"->"Template Content" box?

Comment: Hi you can use by update in sales email configuration settings. Create a template in Admin->Marketing->Email template (for example template name is  "custom order update") then go to store->configuration->sales->sales email->Order Comments (which is may be use for order update email)->select your template in "Order Comment Email Template".

Comment: Yeah that i selected. only i need to insert "if condition" in my  "custom order update" in my email template.

Comment: I also check that "if condition" is not working and i personally tested my code and it working well. you just need to update correct email template by guest and current theme. like in default it use (order update Magento/luma) and configure it in configuration settings

Comment: Hi @Amith, Please check my updated question on top.

Comment: @mohama, please check by update order by comment with notifying to the customer. 
I see from your example for pending it display "some custom text" which shouldn't. Please confirm it displays "other text" for order is pending or any other order status excepted cancel.

Comment: @Amith, Now i re-edit my code like {{if order.getStatusLabel() == 'Canceled'}}

        Canceled

{{/if}} 

 {{if order.getStatusLabel() == 'Pending'}}

       Pending

{{/if}}   my email out put comes like "Canceled Pending " for both status.

Comment: I think the code in curly braces is not executed. the output should be only canceled or only pending. please try my solution once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91111/discussion-between-mohana-and-amitkumar-solanki).

Answer (score 0):

Try below condition, It may help.

```
{{if $order.getStatusLabel()=='Canceled'}}

     <strong>CANCELED - THERE, ARE YOU HAPPY?!</strong>

{{else}}

     {{var $order.getStatusLabel() }}

{{/if}}
```

Comment: No it's not working.

Comment: @mohana, I have edited my code, Try it again if it works

Comment: No, it's also not working.